# Google Music won't cache my songs?

Tags: music, music-player, google-play-music, bugs, cache

I haven't updated my Google Music in ages (I still had the blue interface) but when I updated it to the latest version, I had to clear my song cache because some of my music weren't playing correctly. This time around, it seems to stream the music all the time. I only have internet when I'm around wifi and I rely heavily on its caching so I can listen while on the road or offline. I didn't even have to specifically mark my songs as "Offline" on the older version I had, they just get stored as soon as I finished streaming them once.

So, what gives? Also, I assumed that they simply changed the behavior so that I am required to tick on the "keep offline" option this time around but I can't even find that option anywhere. Is this issue happening to other Google Music users?